# pasting x number of strings to y number of strings using sapply

Tags: r

I have two vectors, vector "t" is times, vector "d" is dates.
I want to extract data for all times in t for all dates in d
I know how to format the dates to POSIXct from character so this isn't the issue, I tried to use  sapply to go over the days one by one the code I used was as follows:

```
    t <- c("11:25:30", "12:00:00", "15:31:25", "19:15:48", "23:51:06")
    d <- c("2013-01-17", "2013-01-24", "2013-02-09", "2013-02-11")  
    c1 <- sapply(d, function(i) paste(d[i],t))
```

I expected to see a list if used lapply or a vector when using sapply with the strings "
"2013-01-17 11:25:30", "2013-01-17 12:00:00", 2013-01-17 15:31:25" ... al the way to the end combining each date with all times in t.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the fastest way and has the added benefit of the least amount of typing:

```
c(outer(d, t, paste))

##  [1] "2013-01-17 11:25:30" "2013-01-24 11:25:30" "2013-02-09 11:25:30"
##  [4] "2013-02-11 11:25:30" "2013-01-17 12:00:00" "2013-01-24 12:00:00"
##  [7] "2013-02-09 12:00:00" "2013-02-11 12:00:00" "2013-01-17 15:31:25"
## [10] "2013-01-24 15:31:25" "2013-02-09 15:31:25" "2013-02-11 15:31:25"
## [13] "2013-01-17 19:15:48" "2013-01-24 19:15:48" "2013-02-09 19:15:48"
## [16] "2013-02-11 19:15:48" "2013-01-17 23:51:06" "2013-01-24 23:51:06"
## [19] "2013-02-09 23:51:06" "2013-02-11 23:51:06"
```

Comment: +1, nice and short. Good to see there is always one more way to accomplishing something in R.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `expand.grid()` with `apply()`. expand.grid() will make data frame of all posible combinations of `d` and `t`. The with `apply()` function `paste()` is applied to each row of this data frame. `collapse=" "` ensures that string are put together and space put between them.

```
apply(expand.grid(d,t),1,paste,collapse=" ")

 [1] "2013-01-17 11:25:30" "2013-01-24 11:25:30" "2013-02-09 11:25:30"
 [4] "2013-02-11 11:25:30" "2013-01-17 12:00:00" "2013-01-24 12:00:00"
 [7] "2013-02-09 12:00:00" "2013-02-11 12:00:00" "2013-01-17 15:31:25"
[10] "2013-01-24 15:31:25" "2013-02-09 15:31:25" "2013-02-11 15:31:25"
[13] "2013-01-17 19:15:48" "2013-01-24 19:15:48" "2013-02-09 19:15:48"
[16] "2013-02-11 19:15:48" "2013-01-17 23:51:06" "2013-01-24 23:51:06"
[19] "2013-02-09 23:51:06" "2013-02-11 23:51:06"
```

Comment: @PaulHiemstra (+1) not using do.call() to often , so forgot about this

Comment: Always a sport to find the shortest one-liner to fix the problem. Your solution is perfectly valid, nicely done. The most important gotcha is probably the use of `expand.grid`.

Comment: Both are valid thanks to both.  I haven't used expand.grid before or the do.call. But this is great, I learned a lot.  I will be looking them both up.  But just for a quick understanding of the code logic, I am assuming expand.grid(d,t) is putting d,t together into a virtual data.frame that ignores the difference in their length, then we apply the paste function to each row of this virtual data.frame. is this the general logic of this code?

Comment: Yes, exactly. expand.grid() makes data frame of all possible combinations of d and t, and then paste() is applied to each row if this data frame.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `expand.grid` and `paste` like this:

```
t <- c("11:25:30", "12:00:00", "15:31:25", "19:15:48", "23:51:06")
d <- c("2013-01-17", "2013-01-24", "2013-02-09", "2013-02-11") 
do.call("paste", expand.grid(d,t))
 [1] "2013-01-17 11:25:30" "2013-01-24 11:25:30" "2013-02-09 11:25:30"
 [4] "2013-02-11 11:25:30" "2013-01-17 12:00:00" "2013-01-24 12:00:00"
 [7] "2013-02-09 12:00:00" "2013-02-11 12:00:00" "2013-01-17 15:31:25"
[10] "2013-01-24 15:31:25" "2013-02-09 15:31:25" "2013-02-11 15:31:25"
[13] "2013-01-17 19:15:48" "2013-01-24 19:15:48" "2013-02-09 19:15:48"
[16] "2013-02-11 19:15:48" "2013-01-17 23:51:06" "2013-01-24 23:51:06"
[19] "2013-02-09 23:51:06" "2013-02-11 23:51:06"
```

I haven't found a way to tweak the `sep` parameter of `paste` using this syntax, but it gives the output you need.